# How do I make this program more detailed and tell me the winning percentages after I played it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

So far, this craps game works in python but I need to add the winning percentage after you played it. Plus, how do I make it where the players response has to be "yes" or "no" in order to run? It will run no matter what. And is there way to replace "break" in this program?

```
import random
first_roll = 0

def play():
    yesOrno = str(input('Would you like to play? '))
    yesOrno = yesOrno[0].lower()


    while yesOrno == 'y':
        throw_1 = random.randint(1,6)
        throw_2 = random.randint(1,6)
        total = throw_1 + throw_2


        if total == (2,12):
            yesOrno = str(input('You lost! Would you like to play again?'))
            yesOrno = yesOrno[0].lower()

        elif total == (7,11):
            yesOrno == str(input('You won! Would you like to play again?'))
            yesOrno = yesOrno[0].lower()

        else:
            first_roll == total

            while yesOrno == 'y':
                throw_1 = random.randint(1,6)
                throw_2 = random.randint(1,6)
                finalRoll = throw_1 + throw_2

                print('You rolled a',total)

                if total == 2 or 3 or 7 or 11 or 12:
                    yesOrno = str(input('You lost! Would you like to play again?'))
                    yesOrno = yesOrno[0].lower()
                    break

                elif total == first_roll:
                    yesOrno = str(input('You won! Would you like to play again?'))
                    yesOrno = yesOrno[0].lower()
                    break

                else:
                    yesOrno == 'y'

    print('Thanks for playing!')

play()
```

Comment: There are many potential improvements to be made to the code, but as far as re-run goes, that part works. It will only play again if you answer `y` to the `Would you like to play again?` question. However, your first tests `if total == (2, 12):` and `if total == (7, 11):` should more likely be `if total in (2,12):` and `if total in (7, 11):` respectively. Thus change the equality test (`==`) to `in`. Still, this is not a bad start for someone new to Python and programming.

Comment: this: `if total == 2 or 3 or 7 or 11 or 12:` is not how  python comparison works. It will evaluate to `True` all the time as 2 is truthy, 3is truthy etc. obly 0 is falsy. Use `if total in { 2 , 3 , 7 , 11 , 12}:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed and streamlined some of your code. I created 2 helpers for repetetive tasks:

```
import random

def askPlayAgain(text=""):
    """Ask for y or n, loop until given. Maybe add 'text' before the message."""
    t = ""
    while t not in {"y","n"}:
        t = input("\n" + text + 'Would you like to play? [y/n]').strip()[0].lower()
    return t

def getSumDices(n=2,sides=6):
    """Get sum of 'n' random dices with 'sides' sides"""
    return sum(random.choices(range(1,sides+1),k=n)) # range(1,7) = 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

and modified the play logic slightly:

```
def play():
    first_roll = 0
    win = 0
    lost = 0

    yesOrno = askPlayAgain()

    while yesOrno == 'y':

        # dont need the individual dices - just the sum
        # you can get both rolls at once
        total = getSumDices()         
        print('You rolled a', total)

        if total in {2,12}:
            lost += 1
            yesOrno = askPlayAgain("You lost! ") 

        elif total in {7,11}:
            win += 1
            yesOrno == askPlayAgain("You won! ") 
        else:
            # remember last rounds result
            first_roll = total

            while True:
                total = getSumDices()         
                print('You rolled a', total)

                # this is kinda unfair, if you had 3 in your first round
                # you cant win the second round at all ...
                if total in {2,3,7,11,12}:
                    lost += 1
                    yesOrno = askPlayAgain("You lost! ")
                    break
                elif total == first_roll:
                    win += 1
                    yesOrno = askPlayAgain("You won! ")
                    break

    print('Thanks for playing!')
    print('{} wins vs {} lost'.format(win,lost))

play()
```

Output:

```
Would you like to play? [y/n]y
You rolled a 10
You rolled a 12

You lost! Would you like to play? [y/n]y
You rolled a 9
You rolled a 7

You lost! Would you like to play? [y/n]y
You rolled a 7

You won! Would you like to play? [y/n]y
You rolled a 6
You rolled a 10
You rolled a 3

You lost! Would you like to play? [y/n]y
You rolled a 8
You rolled a 9
You rolled a 11

You lost! Would you like to play? [y/n]n
Thanks for playing!
1 wins vs 4 lost
```

Comment: Dear DV - in case you come back - hint @ what was not useful so I can adjust the answer accordingly. Thanks